# Multiple shipping method for single order

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping, shipping-methods, quote

I wanted to build a functionality where user can choose or select shipping method per cart item.
For example I have 3 items in my cart as below-

1. Item-1
2. Item-2
3. Item-3

On cart page all the available shipping methods will display against each of these items. And user can select the different shipping method for each cart item as below-

1. Item-1 : Free delivery
2. Item-2 : Table Rates
3. Item-3 : flat rate

Can anyone suggest a way by which this can be acheived?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi manish_khot, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lot and a lot or rewritting in the magento process. I don't say it's impossible but I think it's a lot of headache for an uncertain result.

I would suggest changing the approach.

- Step 1 : Create a custom shipping method.
- Step 2 : For each order item specify a new attributes called custom_delivery_method for example.
- Step 3 : In your custom shipping method you can calculate the price using the new attributes defined on each order item.

This way you keep one shipping method for the order but you simulate the fact that you have many of them. Then your vendor can process the new information for the delivery anyway in the order details.

Also, May be updating the process of invoice too to print this new information in the invoice pdf.